# No me aparece un campo en la lista al momento de guardarlo

Tags: java, openxava

Tengo mis clases de Proveedor y Correo. Proveedor es entity y correo embeddable dentro de proveedor. En la interfaz de OpenXava si me aparece los campos de proveedor y el correo, sin embargo, al momento de guardar y mostrar la lista, no aparece el correo. Intente poner Correo.corre en Proveedor pero me dio error. Gracias de antemano.
Esta es mi clase Proveedor:

````
```package com.uam.CLINICA.model;
import java.util.;
import javax.persistence.;
import com.uam.CLINICA.Calculadores.ValidadorProveedor;
import org.openxava.annotations.*;

import lombok.*;

@Entity @Getter @Setter
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="Proveedor.findByNombre",query="select e from Proveedor e where e.nombre like ?1")
})
@View(name="Simple",members = "nombre,compania, correo")
public class Proveedor extends Identificable{

@PropertyValidator(value= ValidadorProveedor.class)
@Required
private String nombre;

@Column(length = 20)
@Required
String compania;

@ElementCollection
@ListProperties("correo")
private Collection<Correo> correo;
}```
y esta mi clase Correo:
```package com.uam.CLINICA.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import com.uam.CLINICA.Calculadores.CorreoValidador;
import lombok.*;
import org.openxava.annotations.PropertyValidator;
import org.openxava.annotations.View;

@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@View(name="Simple",members = "correo")
public class Correo {

@PropertyValidator(value = CorreoValidador.class)
private String correo;
}```
````

[image: asi aparece en OpenXava]

Answer (score 0):

Claro, porque correo es una colección en proveedor. Un proveedor podría tener 457 correos, ¿cómo podríamos visualizar eso en una celda? Por esa razón, por defecto no se añaden las colecciones.

Sí que la puedes añadir si usas la anotación @Tab, así:

```
@Tab("nombre, compania, correo.correo")
public class Proveedor extends Identificable {
```

En este caso la columna aparecerá, pero vacía, sin datos. Esto es útil para poder filtrar por ese campo. No aparecen datos, porque es una colección. Aunque tu a la colección le hayas puesto un nombre en singular, correo, sigue siendo una colección que puede contener muchos datos.